# Sql Server transaction log placement in AWS hosting

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2

When running a server on amazon aws, is there any point to placing a sql server transaction log on a separate volume from the database?   Of course if I had control of the physical environment I'd place the tlog on a separate spindle or raid array.  But in AWS-EC2, the windows volumes will be mapped to any number of physical drives in some unknown configuration so I'm thinking no, there's no point in it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the db and logs are on the same EBS volume, you **know** they'll be competing for spindle time. At least if they're on separate EBS volumes, even if you don't know with certainty that they're on different spindles, at least there's a chance that they're on different hardware.

In addition to performance, there are several other benefits to separating them out.

Comment: Besides performance, what are the benefits?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read up [SQL Server in EC2](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/09/sql-server-ec/), there is also a video available [Configuring SQL Server in Amazon EC2: Training Video](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/09/configuring-sql-server-amazon-ec2-training-video/).

Comment: This is now quite old.